# Deploy and debug application on OC4J in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, oc4j

I have a tomcat webapp project checked out in eclipse (call it 'xyz'). I use eclipse tomcat plugin with Devloader. Everything runs fine. etc, etc, happy.

Now I want to run the same project on OC4J app server and debug in eclipse. For that, I have downloaded and installed standalone OC4J server. I created a OC4J server instance in eclipse. Question is how do I deploy the earlier checked out project 'xyz' to run on OC4J server in eclipse.

Additionally, is there any plugin for OC4J similar to tomcat in eclipse, that makes life easier.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Package your application in an EAR file and deploy it to OC4J
2. Start OC4J with VM arguments that enable remote debugging (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html)
3. Create a Debug Configuration of type Remote Java Application in Eclipse, and use that to connect to the running VM